# Python merge two counter objects, keeping the largest sum

Tags: python, counter

If I have two counter objects and I would like to merge them, adding new values from one and keeping the largest count if the two counters contain the same values.

```
Counter a = { "apple":3, "peach":1, "pears":7, "watermelon":2, "grapes":7 }

Counter b = { "apple":12, "kiwi":9, "grapes":2, "pears":21, "pineapple":2, "oranges":2 }

#desired output
counter c = { "apple":12, "pears":21, "grapes":7 "peach":1, "watermelon":2, "pineapple":2, "oranges":2}
```

Currently I've tried updating the counter but that seems to merge the two counters but sums their counts. I would just like to merge the counters and keep the largest value or add to the counter if there isn't one already.

Comment: Your question says "adding new values" but your desired output contains only the common ones.

Comment: @DeepSpace you are correct, I already had the intersection of the two counters, but i'd also like to add the unique items as well. I hope that clarifies the initial question.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40780812/1453822

Comment: @user1610950 When editing your question, it is perfectly acceptable to remove the mistake and just leave the corrected version (just edit the last line of your code) - you do not have to maintain the old and add an edit section.  It is ok if you want to do it that way, but for future readers of the question, it may be clearer if it is just corrected.

Comment: @Matthew thanks, I made the suggested edits. DeepSpace, thanks that's a really concise answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After OP edited their question, the desired output can be achieved by simply using the bitwise or (`|`) operator:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({ "apple":3, "peach":1, "pears":7, "watermelon":2, "grapes":7 })

b = Counter({ "apple":12, "kiwi":9, "grapes":2, "pears":21, "pineapple":2, "oranges":2 })

c = a | b

print(c)
>> Counter({'pears': 21, 'apple': 12, 'kiwi': 9, 'grapes': 7, 'watermelon': 2, 'oranges': 2,
            'pineapple': 2, 'peach': 1})
```

Comment: @Akaberto What do you mean?

Comment: As in, bitwise or give 1|4 == 5

Comment: @Akaberto Try it yourself and you'll see that it works.

Comment: Missed that this operator was overloaded for this.  My bad.  Was only thinking of how normal '|' operator works.  The bitwise one.

Comment: "kiwi" should not appear in the resulting counter, based on the provided example in the question.
The question is asking for the intersection which keeps the -maximum- value and not the minimum, as Python by default does.

Answer (score 2):

You could take distinct keys from each of the `Counter`'s using inbuilt `a&b`, and use them to get your desired max logic like this:

```
Counter({key:max(a[key], b[key]) for key in a&b})
```

Here is a sample run:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a=Counter({ "apple":3, "peach":1, "pears":7, "watermelon":2, "grapes":7 })
>>> b=Counter({ "apple":12, "kiwi":9, "grapes":2, "pears":21, "pineapple":2, "oranges":2 })
>>> Counter({key:max(a[key], b[key]) for key in a&b})
Counter({'pears': 21, 'apple': 12, 'grapes': 7})
>>>
```

Note that if you wanted the minimum for common elements that is already built in python with this construct:

```
>>> a&b
Counter({'pears': 7, 'apple': 3, 'grapes': 2})
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the intersection of the keys in two counters and iterate over it in dict comprehension while using `max` to get greatest value:

```
>>> a = Counter({ "apple":3, "peach":1, "pears":7, "watermelon":2, "grapes":7 })
>>> b = Counter({ "apple":12, "kiwi":9, "grapes":2, "pears":21, "pineapple":2, "oranges":2 })
>>> Counter({k: max(a[k], b[k]) for k in a.keys() & b.keys()})
Counter({'pears': 21, 'apple': 12, 'grapes': 7})
```

Note that above will work only on Python 3, on Python 2 you need to call [`viewkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) instead:

```
>>> Counter({k: max(a[k], b[k]) for k in a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys()})
Counter({'pears': 21, 'apple': 12, 'grapes': 7})
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you have arbitrarily many Counters to merge, you can use the `__or__` operator in conjunction with `reduce` on an iterable like so:

```py
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({ "apple":3, "peach":1, "pears":7, "watermelon":2, "grapes":7 })
b = Counter({ "apple":12, "kiwi":9, "grapes":2, "pears":21, "pineapple":2, "oranges":2 })
counters = [a,b]

c = reduce(Counter.__or__, counters)

print(c)
```

gives you: `Counter({'pears': 21, 'apple': 12, 'kiwi': 9, 'grapes': 7, 'watermelon': 2, 'pineapple': 2, 'oranges': 2, 'peach': 1})`

Comment: What's interesting is if you just use the builtin `or` it doesn't use the `Counter.__or__` which correctly implements this behavior.

`Counter('abcd') or Counter('abcddd')` --> `Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})`
whereas
`Counter.__or__(Counter('abcd'), Counter('abcddd'))` --> `Counter({'d': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})`